# If $f: (-1,1)→M_n(\mathbb R)$ be a $C^1$ map such that $f(0)=I$ and $f(t)\in O(n)$ ,show that $Df(0)$ exists and is a skew-symmetric matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, matrix-calculus, orthogonal-matrices

If $f: (-1,1)→M_n(\mathbb R)$ be a $C^1$ map such that $f(0)=I$ and $f(t)\in O(n)$ ,show that $Df(0)$ exists is skew-symmetric . matrix

Actually, we have $f(t).f(t)^T=I$ for all $t,$ and we are to find the limit $\frac{\|f(h)-f(0)\|}{h}$ , but how to differentiate $f(t).f(t)^T=I$ in both sides ??

$f(t)$ can be thought as points in $\mathbb R^{n^2}$ and applying derivative component-wise, we have
$f(t).f'(t)^T + f'(t).f(t)^T =0$ and by using $f(0)=I$ ,we get the desired result.

Now, is the converse true? For any skew-symmetric matrix $A$, does there exist a curve $g$ with $g(0)=I$ and $Dg(0)=A?$

I think $g(t)=exp(tA)$ will work

A small hint is required , thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by $f(t) \in O(n)$?

Comment: $f(t)$ is a real,orthogonal matrix for all $t.$

Comment: Doesn't $f\in C^1$ imply $f'(0)$ exists?

Comment: If this is homework, you should show us what you've tried. You should think about the product rule. For the converse, it all depends what you know. You haven't given any indication of what you know or what tools you have.

Comment: What happens at $t=0$?

Comment: Can you please give me a hint of the converse?

Comment: the fact that $f(t)$ is path connected to the identity tells you that you really should be writing $f(t)\in SO(n)$